# Make chart series rise when number of rows rise

Tags: macos, numbers

I have spreadsheet that I'm updating every day with new numbers. Each day I'm adding new number to new row.

I need to create chart that has series from those rows but I don't want to edit data series every day. I want that my chart update dynamically when I add new rows with new data. Is there any way to add formula in Series Value field (look at screenshot)? So far I see I can only add range. When I try to write in this field e.g. Indirect function I just can't write it there. I think this is silly question and this is easy to solve but I just cant figure it out how to do this with Numbers. I'm moving from Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to refer to your Value set by name rather than cell-address-range. Example procedure, starting from your example chart:

1. Ensure Table 1 row 1 is a Header Row
2. Put a cosmetic name in B1, naming your column B series, say… `Series`
3. Change the Chart's Data Value field from a cell reference to the new column header name, e.g. `Table 1::Series`

Since the chart is now set to simply reflect all of that column's data, it will update live as new data appears.